# Centering a world map with Google Charts

Tags: google-visualization

I've got a Google Chart.  However the auto centre isn't in a very pretty place (It slices Africa in half).  I want the edge to be on the border between Russia and Alaska but for the life of me I can't get it to do it.

Here's the link:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=map&chs=480x250&chld=NG|TR||KE|JO|CM|ZA|SA|GM|BH|ET|OM|AO|||IN|CN|TW|JP|NZ|AU||LK|PK|SG|BD|HK|MY|GB|DE|FR|GR|NL|RO|ES|PT|RU|IT|CZ|NO|SK|BE|PL|MT|DK|LT|CH|FI|CS|BG|AT|IS|HR|US|CA|MX|BB|GY|CL|VE|SR|AG|BR|HN|EC&chco=666666|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13
```

And the resultant image:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=map:fixed=-40,-178,84,178&chs=400x250&chld=NG|TR||KE|JO|CM|ZA|SA|GM|BH|ET|OM|AO|||IN|CN|TW|JP|NZ|AU||LK|PK|SG|BD|HK|MY|GB|DE|FR|GR|NL|RO|ES|PT|RU|IT|CZ|NO|SK|BE|PL|MT|DK|LT|CH|FI|CS|BG|AT|IS|HR|US|CA|MX|BB|GY|CL|VE|SR|AG|BR|HN|EC&chco=666666|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13|DD0E13
```

With...

```
?cht=map:fixed=-40,-178,84,178
```

being the dimensions for centering it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=map:auto:fixed=-60,-170,84,178&chs=630x400&chld=BR&chco=B3BCC0|518274

Centering a world map with Google Charts

[image]